# Opencart order confirmation email subject is empty

Tags: php, email, opencart

My opencart does not input into the order confirmation email subject. The email comes with no subject. Any idea why that happens?

I cannot figure out, what could be the problem. Any ideas are appreciated.

Thank you in advance

```
    <?php
class Mail {
    protected $to;
    protected $from;
    protected $sender;
    protected $subject;
    protected $text;
    protected $html;
    protected $attachments = array();
    public $protocol = 'mail';
    public $hostname;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $port = 25;
    public $timeout = 5;
    public $newline = "\n";
    public $crlf = "\r\n";
    public $verp = false;
    public $parameter = '';

    public function setTo($to) {
        $this->to = $to;
    }

    public function setFrom($from) {
        $this->from = $from;
    }

    public function setSender($sender) {
        $this->sender = $sender;
    }

    public function setSubject($subject) {
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }

    public function setText($text) {
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    public function setHtml($html) {
        $this->html = $html;
    }

    public function addAttachment($filename) {
        $this->attachments[] = $filename;
    }

    public function send() {
        if (!$this->to) {
            trigger_error('Error: E-Mail to required!');
            exit();         
        }

        if (!$this->from) {
            trigger_error('Error: E-Mail from required!');
            exit();                 
        }

        if (!$this->sender) {
            trigger_error('Error: E-Mail sender required!');
            exit();                 
        }

        if (!$this->subject) {
            trigger_error('Error: E-Mail subject required!');
            exit();                 
        }

        if ((!$this->text) && (!$this->html)) {
            trigger_error('Error: E-Mail message required!');
            exit();                 
        }

        if (is_array($this->to)) {
            $to = implode(',', $this->to);
        } else {
            $to = $this->to;
        }

        $boundary = '----=_NextPart_' . md5(time());

        $header = '';

        $header .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $this->newline;

        if ($this->protocol != 'mail') {
            $header .= 'To: ' . $to . $this->newline;
            $header .= 'Subject: ' . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=' . $this->newline;
        }

        $header .= 'Date: ' . date('D, d M Y H:i:s O') . $this->newline;
        $header = 'From: ' . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->sender) . '?=' . ' <' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
        $header .= 'Reply-To: ' . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->sender) . '?=' . ' <' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
        $header .= 'Return-Path: ' . $this->from . $this->newline;
        $header .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . $this->newline;
        $header .= 'Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . $this->newline . $this->newline;

        if (!$this->html) {
            $message  = '--' . $boundary . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . $this->newline . $this->newline;
            $message .= $this->text . $this->newline;
        } else {
            $message  = '--' . $boundary . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="' . $boundary . '_alt"' . $this->newline . $this->newline;
            $message .= '--' . $boundary . '_alt' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . $this->newline . $this->newline;

            if ($this->text) {
                $message .= $this->text . $this->newline;
            } else {
                $message .= 'This is a HTML email and your email client software does not support HTML email!' . $this->newline;
            }

            $message .= '--' . $boundary . '_alt' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . $this->newline . $this->newline;
            $message .= $this->html . $this->newline;
            $message .= '--' . $boundary . '_alt--' . $this->newline;
        }

        foreach ($this->attachments as $attachment) {
            if (file_exists($attachment)) {
                $handle = fopen($attachment, 'r');

                $content = fread($handle, filesize($attachment));

                fclose($handle);

                $message .= '--' . $boundary . $this->newline;
                $message .= 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="' . basename($attachment) . '"' . $this->newline;
                $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . $this->newline;
                $message .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($attachment) . '"' . $this->newline;
                $message .= 'Content-ID: <' . basename(urlencode($attachment)) . '>' . $this->newline;
                $message .= 'X-Attachment-Id: ' . basename(urlencode($attachment)) . $this->newline . $this->newline;
                $message .= chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
            }
        }

        $message .= '--' . $boundary . '--' . $this->newline;

        if ($this->protocol == 'mail') {
            ini_set('sendmail_from', $this->from);

            if ($this->parameter) {
                mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=', $message, $header, $this->parameter);
            } else {
                mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=', $message, $header);
            }
        } elseif ($this->protocol == 'smtp') {
            $handle = fsockopen($this->hostname, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout);

            if (!$handle) {
                trigger_error('Error: ' . $errstr . ' (' . $errno . ')');
                exit();                 
            } else {
                if (substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) != 'WIN') {
                    socket_set_timeout($handle, $this->timeout, 0);
                }

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($this->hostname, 0, 3) == 'tls') {
                    fputs($handle, 'STARTTLS' . $this->crlf);

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 220) {
                        trigger_error('Error: STARTTLS not accepted from server!');
                        exit();                             
                    }
                }

                if (!empty($this->username)  && !empty($this->password)) {
                    fputs($handle, 'EHLO ' . getenv('SERVER_NAME') . $this->crlf);

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                        trigger_error('Error: EHLO not accepted from server!');
                        exit();                             
                    }

                    fputs($handle, 'AUTH LOGIN' . $this->crlf);

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 334) {
                        trigger_error('Error: AUTH LOGIN not accepted from server!');
                        exit();                     
                    }

                    fputs($handle, base64_encode($this->username) . $this->crlf);

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 334) {
                        trigger_error('Error: Username not accepted from server!');
                        exit();                             
                    }

                    fputs($handle, base64_encode($this->password) . $this->crlf);

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 235) {
                        trigger_error('Error: Password not accepted from server!');
                        exit();                             
                    }
                } else {
                    fputs($handle, 'HELO ' . getenv('SERVER_NAME') . $this->crlf);

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                        trigger_error('Error: HELO not accepted from server!');
                        exit();                         
                    }
                }

                if ($this->verp) {
                    fputs($handle, 'MAIL FROM: <' . $this->from . '>XVERP' . $this->crlf);
                } else {
                    fputs($handle, 'MAIL FROM: <' . $this->from . '>' . $this->crlf);
                }

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                    trigger_error('Error: MAIL FROM not accepted from server!');
                    exit();                         
                }

                if (!is_array($this->to)) {
                    fputs($handle, 'RCPT TO: <' . $this->to . '>' . $this->crlf);

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if ((substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) && (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 251)) {
                        trigger_error('Error: RCPT TO not accepted from server!');
                        exit();                         
                    }
                } else {
                    foreach ($this->to as $recipient) {
                        fputs($handle, 'RCPT TO: <' . $recipient . '>' . $this->crlf);

                        $reply = '';

                        while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                            $reply .= $line;

                            if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if ((substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) && (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 251)) {
                            trigger_error('Error: RCPT TO not accepted from server!');
                            exit();                             
                        }
                    }
                }

                fputs($handle, 'DATA' . $this->crlf);

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 354) {
                    trigger_error('Error: DATA not accepted from server!');
                    exit();                     
                }

                // According to rfc 821 we should not send more than 1000 including the CRLF
                $message = str_replace("\r\n", "\n",  $header . $message);
                $message = str_replace("\r", "\n", $message);

                $lines = explode("\n", $message);

                foreach ($lines as $line) {
                    $results = str_split($line, 998);

                    foreach ($results as $result) {
                        if (substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) != 'WIN') {
                            fputs($handle, $result . $this->crlf);
                        } else {
                            fputs($handle, str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $result) . $this->crlf);
                        }                           
                    }
                }

                fputs($handle, '.' . $this->crlf);

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                    trigger_error('Error: DATA not accepted from server!');
                    exit();                     
                }

                fputs($handle, 'QUIT' . $this->crlf);

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 221) {
                    trigger_error('Error: QUIT not accepted from server!');
                    exit();                     
                }

                fclose($handle);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This class, seems not to be the problem. Could you add the rendered html of your form? Just the relevant part please.

Comment: Could you please specify by what you mean rendered html of the form? The email is the confirmation email we get after a customer places an order on the website.

Answer (score 1):

when you right the code for mail in the model section will you use this??

```
$mail = new Mail();
$mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
$mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
$mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
$mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
$mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
$mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
$mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');             
$mail->setTo($order_info['email']);
$mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
$mail->setSender($order_info['store_name']);
$mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mail->setText(html_entity_decode($message, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mail->send();
```

Comment: I do not quite understand your comment. Could you please clarify?

Comment: you have pase this code, where you call the mail function, in the controller or model. if you dont $mail->setSubject this, your mail subject will be blank.

Comment: so what line should i add to the file specified?

Comment: all the placed where you should call the send mail function.

Answer (score 0):

The mail is generated from model/checkout/order in function addOrderHistory(). You might want to see from there. This way you could solve the issue.

Comment: I have checked other emails, actually the problem is not with that, because no email has subject

Comment: Search for `$mail->setSubject($subject);` in your model/checkout/order. See if $subject has anything in it. echo it. Enter a manual subject just to check it. You can do it by `$mail->setSubject('Test Subject');`

Comment: in the destination you specified there is no ,,$mail->setSubject($subject);" ....i forgot to input that i am using 1.5.6.4 version.